# Flex hide tab in TabNavigator

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

How to hide a tab in TabNavigator and also remove the empty space from it?

Example code:

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="TabNavigator">
        <s:NavigatorContent id="tab1" label="Tab 1">
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent id="tab2" label="Tab 2">
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent id="tab3" label="Tab 3">
        </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:TabNavigator>
```

We can hide a tab via `TabNavigator.getTabAt(1).visible = false;`. But this will left an empty space between `Tab 1` and `Tab3`. I don't want to use `TabNavigator.removeChildAt(1);` because the program may need to show `Tab 2` again.

So, how to temporary remove a tab in TabNavigator and also the empty space from it?

Thank you.

Comment: I tend to use the [Spark TabBar](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/TabBar.html) in combination with states, because it gives me more control. In this case you could simply add/remove items from the TabBar's dataProvider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In action script you can do it. Just use id of navigatorcontent to set visible or includeinlayout. When you require make it true else make it false.

Default set to false. When you need make it true in AS.

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="TabNavigator">
    <s:NavigatorContent id="tab1" label="Tab 1" visible="false"  includeInLayout="false">
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent id="tab2" label="Tab 2">
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent id="tab3" label="Tab 3">
    </s:NavigatorContent>
```